# uploading video to Facebook in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to implement video uploading via Facebook in my app. I was using ESSVideoShare but that stopped working with Facebook, I assume due to some recent update on Facebook's part. I followed their guide to implement video sharing [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/), but instead of using a video included in the app I want to allow the user to pick a video from UIImagePicker that then uploads to Facebook. I changed this part:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
```

to this, where videoURL is the url of the chosen video from UIImagePicker, and what I'm using to upload to other services with success:

```
NSString *filePath = [videoURL absoluteString];
```

Everything else I followed the instructions exactly. Once I chose my video in UIImagePicker it opened the Facebook app, asked for permissions for my app to access the profile and post, and then nothing. Just a blank white popover controller over the main Facebook app. If I try to run it again it just tells me that I've already authorized the app, so I click OK and it brings me to the same white screen. I'm guessing it has something to do with my file path but I'm not sure what the proper way to do it would be, I thought this would be correct. Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Edit: I didn't implement SSO because in theory I'd like users to be able to sign onto a different Facebook account than the one that's logged in on the device, but that's apparently moot because it just automatically opened up in the account that's logged in on the Facebook app.

Edit 2: Upon further investigation it looks like the fbDidLogin method isn't getting called at all, which explains why the video isn't being uploaded, but I'm not sure how to fix that as I'm most certainly logged into a Facebook account on the device I'm testing on.